# Print button in Windows 8 Store app HTML + JS for Split Template app

Tags: list, windows-8, printing, split, winjs

I have an app made in WinJS for Windows 8 App store, and I use the Split Page template. So on the split page I have two colums the one named `List column` and the one named `Item detail column`. It is for recipes, and in the list are the pictures and small details, and in the right in the item detail block is the recipe with details and pictures. I want a Print button that will print only the right column with details, not the entire windows with list and etc.

Can someone give me an example better than the one from msdn?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As taken from codeshow.codeplex.com to print a fragment:

```
 function printFrag(printEvent) {
        var printTask = printEvent.request.createPrintTask("codeSHOW Print Frag", function (args) {
            var frag = document.createDocumentFragment();
            frag.appendChild(q(".print #printFromApp").cloneNode(true));
            args.setSource(MSApp.getHtmlPrintDocumentSource(frag));
            // Register the handler for print task completion event
            printTask.oncompleted = printTaskCompleted;
        });
    }
```

Which is in turn cloning this html node and then printing it

```
<div id="printFromApp">
    <h2>Invoke print</h2>
    <p>Wow, printing is fun.</p>
    <button id="invokePrint">Print</button>
</div>
```

All the print samples can be mostly cut and pasted from there, check it out. It's also available in the Windows Store and is an essential HTML/JS dev tool for Windows Store apps.